# redirect a url(s) to a sub/subfolder with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect a sub/sub folder url to a specific URL.

It works with normal redirections like:

```
Redirect /folder https://mydomain.com/therestoftheurl
```

But i need alot of folder/folder1 or folder/folder2 redirections. 
It won't work with this:

```
Redirect /folder/folder1 https://domain.com/target
```

I found a reverse Question about this with this solution.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.in$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.in$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So if i'm not misstaken I could use this without "!" like so. But i think i'm missing something.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.in$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.in$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/folder$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and then the redirections which i don't know at this moment to write. 
Thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to re-order your directives so that the one with subfolders come before the parent redirect:

```
Redirect /folder/folder1 https://domain.com/target
Redirect /folder https://mydomain.com/therestoftheurl
```